# Why are there no faces drawn on the black heads?

Tags: minifigures, star-wars

There were two black heads in the Star Wars 2011 advent calendar and neither had a face drawn. Is that because there was no face necessary since it was going to be covered with a mask anyway or is there a rule that the faces only go on the yellow heads?

Comment: City or Star Wars, which year?

Comment: It's not just the yellow heads - the pink and brown ones from licenses also have faces printed on them.

Comment: Related: http://www.brickset.com/news/article/?ID=2186

Comment: Can you add a picture please?

Comment: @daviesgeek Not sure a picture would add anything . . . it's a head  piece made out of black pvc instead of yellow pvc with nothing painted on it.

Answer (score 12):

They made them solid black so there are no alignment issues when veiwing the masked minifigures. By leaving them blank LEGO ensured the eye slots always appear black. Side note: The only Stormtroopers seen without helmets in the StarWars Movies were Han and Luke in disguise, therefore Stormtroopers are faceless.

Comment: Only the Scout Troopers tend to have eye sockets in their helmets, and the earlier sets had yellow heads with the "large sunglasses" printed on them: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3626bpse

Comment: Also as storm troopers were "descended" from Clone Troopers, you saw quite a lot of them without helmets in episodes 2 and 3 - I know a lot of us older Fans don't like to talk about them, by they are there ;)

Comment: LOL. You are right. Despite having built sets from the newer movies, I did block them from my memory.

Answer (score 8):

The latest Star Wars sets (for example [9489 - Endor Rebel Trooper & Imperial Trooper Battle Pack](http://brickset.com/detail/?Set=9489-1)) do have faces printed on the black Storm Trooper heads, which doesn't work all that well with the Scout Trooper, unless you put it on backwards:

[image: Stormies without helmets and printed faces]
[image: Without spinning the head around, the Scout Trooper doesn't look good.]

However, looking at them, you can clearly see there are issues with printing on black plastic - the faces aren't quite the right colours (although I'll need to work on some better photos for this to really show).

**Edit to add:**

Noticed while rebuilding the set the other day that [Jango Fett's head](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/3626bpsj) was also black with a printed face, released in 2002:

[image: Jango Fett]

Comment: It almost seems like they want to make it look like a tight "mask" covering everything but the face.

Comment: Indeed, those headgearless troopers seem to wear a balaclava. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

Well, they don't print them because they don't know how are their faces. For example, have you ever seen a stormtrooper's face? No, but that's weird, the stormtroopers were suposed to be clones. Anyway, they don't print them because they or we haven't ever seen a stormtrooper, scoutrooper, or whatever unmasked.

Comment: The latest Storm Trooper figures do have faces printed on them (as [I pointed out in my answer](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/889/56)). And without wanting to spoil anything too much, I suggest you check out Episode II: Attack of the Clones (feel free to skip Episode I until much, much later) ;)